# Sending data from MongoDB to my EJS file without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Project goal:** I am trying to create a language converter app. It will take a string from one textarea, convert all string values via a stored dictionary on a DB, and append this converted string into a second textarea. All of this conversion will be happening on the same **index.ejs** page (**no refreshing/redirecting/etc.**).

**What works:** I am able to POST the string data from my first textarea to **index.ejs** and retrieve all matching dictionary entries in my **app.js**. The "/" path (shown below) is my **index.ejs** file. The values are stored in an array called "convertArrOfArrs".  I am using **Mongoose** to do this on my **app.js**. I have prevented the page from infinite refreshing (due to my POST request) via **res.status(204).send()**.

**What doesn't work:** I can't figure out how to send this array of converted values ("convertArrOfArrs") to my **index.ejs**. I think res.render() doesn't work since I need to stay on the same page.

This is my **app.js** which deals with the POST request.

```
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // entire textarea string
  const txtareaStr = await req.body.phoneticTxtArea;
  // puts string into an array, lowercases it, and removes whitespaces
  const txtareaArr = txtareaStr.trim().toLowerCase().split(" ");

  const convertArrOfArrs = [];
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < txtareaArr.length; i++) {
      // this retrieves the word object based on the database match
      let word = await Word.findOne({ phonetic: txtareaArr[i] });
      // stores array of conversions for each word (ARRAY TO BE SENT!!!)
      convertArrOfArrs.push(word.converted);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR", e);
  }
  // prevents page from infinite refreshing after POST request
  res.status(204).send();
});
```

Please let me know if any other details are needed!

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for displaying the data?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question and add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Are you trying to create a real-time application?

Comment: Hi all thank you for the comments. As I researched my problem more, I discovered jQuery and how it uses AJAX to send/request data without refreshing pages. I will learn more about it and try to implement it in my project. Up until now I think I was trying to do what jQuery does without knowing that something like it existed :)